# Sharing a USB printer in Linux

Tags: networking, printing, printer

I have a USB printer, [HP Envy 4500](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-4500-e-All-in-One-Printer-series/5304875/model/5304876/drivers). Ok, this printer is Wifi too, but it is known that this printer [does not work with a wireless repeater](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/HP-Envy-4500-wireless-stops-working-after-installing-wifi/td-p/4618988).

I can freely print via USB, but I need to physically be next to the printer. Instead I am struggling for VPN printing right now.

My equipment is a Raspberry Pi, so a fully functional **Linux** personal computer. I am not physically in the printer's site while I write this post, so I need to plan my actions

### The question is

If I connect the printer to USB port of Raspberry, which is going to be freely accessed over VPN, can I share the printer, together with its driver, to any other network computer or tablet?

The driver part is important to me, *almost only* because this printer is capable of saving lots of paper by automatic duplex printing. So I *should* use an HP driver to print, I can't simply print to a "generic network printer".

#### Summarizing

- Printer does not have Ethernet networking
- Printer won't connect to wifi if it finds two base stations with same SSID
- I can configure anything that fits the 512MB, if I remember correct, of the [Raspberry Pi Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b-plus/). Cups and Samba included (I never used them)
- I need to duplex-print at least from Windows PC. Seeing printer with HP original driver, printing from tablet or other stuff is only a plus
- Buying a USB print server is not worth the price

Comment: I stupidly posted this on stackoverflow for an unknown reason :-)

Comment: Is this what you need to do? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77073/how-can-i-set-up-a-usb-printer-as-a-network-printer-using-a-linux-server

Comment: I think so. I will have to try when deploying the Raspberry